# Methods to quickly compute percentages

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, arithmetic

Yesterday, talking with a friend of mine, she asked me what is a quick (and – of course – correct) way to compute percentages, say $3.7 \%$ of $149$. Frankly, I was sort of dumbfounded, because I use the following two methods:

- either I use ratios,
- or I start to go on with a sequence of approximations (e.g. I get the $10$% of $149$ and then I proceed by roughly converging towards $4$%, and then I wildly guess...).

In both cases, she was not satisfied: ratios were *too slow*, and the other system... well, you can guess by yourself.

Are there some other options that are both fast (which means that you should not need pencil and paper to make the calculation) and sound?

Please, notice that I am not interested in the result of the example I chose itself: this should rather be a way to show a particular system.

Thank you for your time.

*PS: To the moderators, I was seriously contemplating the idea of using the tag "big list", but I am not sure the topic is that compelling.*

Comment: Did you mean $3.7\%$?

Comment: @barakmanos: Edited

Comment: For the specific example of $149$, calculate the percentage out of $150$ and then subtract the percentage out of $1$. In other words, $3.7\%\cdot149=3.7\%\cdot(150-1)=3.7\%\cdot150-3.7\%\cdot1=3.7\%+1.85\%+0.037\%$.

Comment: @barakmanos: Actually I have some problems with your last equality. Btw, if you write a proper answer I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: I don't see any point in making it a proper answer, because it relates only to the case of $149$. Sometimes it is better to "make use" of the percentage instead (for example, if it divides $100$ with no remainder). But there is no general answer for all cases, unless calculators are allowed. What problems to you have with my last equality?

Comment: @barakmanos: Simply, I don't see where it comes from. Regarding the question and the potential answer, I can agree with you. Indeed, I am not really interested in the specific example at hand (even if I am interested in understanding where your last equality comes from... ;) ). What I was interested in was some sort of a list of the options we have to compute percentages, better if – so to speak – "fast".

Comment: $3.7\%$ out of $150$ is $3.7\%$ out of $100$ plus $3.7\%$ out of $50$, do you understand that?

Comment: I was referring to $3.7 \% + 1.85 \% + 0.037 \%$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to explain. By the way, that $+0.037\%$ should have been $-0.037\%$, sorry.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I did not get it.

Comment: OK, so all the rest is clear then?

Comment: Well, you should also drop the symbol "%", if you write 0.037 (this comment does not apply to the other occurences).

Comment: Yes, of course, should remove the $\%$ from all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I use to evaluate the $1\%$, in your case $1.49$ and multiply for the given percentage: $1.49 \times 3.7$. it is only one multiplication that, if I'm not interesting to exact value I can evaluate approximating the numbers saying that the value is something between $3.5\times 1.5=5.25$ and $4 \times 1.4 = 5.6$.

Comment: Yep, this is kind of close to my way of approximating. But I wanted to see if there is a way that gives you the exact result.

Comment: Sorry, but for the exact value I need pencil and paper ( or my phone) to calculate $1.49 \times 3.7$

Answer (score 0):

3.7% of 100 = 3.7

3.7% of 40 = 4*0.37 = 1.48

3.7% of 9 = 9*0.037 = 0.333

3.7+1.48+0.333=5.513

Comment: First, thanks for the answer. However, two comments in one: can you actually compute it quickly without pencil and paper? I am more interested in the possible ways somebody can solve it. The specific example is not that interesting, unless it is used to show a specific way of solving it.

Comment: there's nothing more to it than 3.7/100*149, it only depends on your mental arithmetic skills. an approximation suffices in most cases, otherwise use a calculator.